# How do I remove libre office configurations

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, configuration, reset, purge

So I was messing around in the **Libre Office** settings and enabled Open GL (Hoping for GL acceleration) . Once I restarted Libre office, It would load, but a window would appear briefly and close. I tried `apt-get purge` and that did not work. As Libre office did the same thing.

So how would I reset my libre office?

(PS: I use Ubuntu 16.04.1)

Comment: which version of LibreOffice ?

Comment: version 5.2, as installed by default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

for LibreOffice 5.2 and older <sup>[ref](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/General/110#Resetting_the_User-Profile)</sup>:

- close LibreOffice including "QuickStart" in system tray
- rename the user profile folder from "user" to "user-old", locations
  for your OS `/home/<user name>/.config/libreoffice/4/user`
- restart LibreOffice and a new user profile will be generated

Test and see if the problem is gone.

- If the problem persists, you can restore the previous profile because
  it was not the cause of the problem. To restore the previous profile,
  delete the new folder and give the old one its former name.
- If the problem is solved, one or more files on your profile are
  corrupted.

Comment: It's my pleasure :)